# Windows 7 64-bit stops sharing of Internet connection with VMware virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, internet-connection

First of all I'm using VMware Workstation, which has it's own Internet connection sharing implemented, but I don't want to use it, as it does not implement the full stack. Things like tracing packet routes in guest operating system don't work.

So I turned this off.

Instead, I shared my wireless connection to VMware virtual network adapter in `Control Panel -> Network Connections` of the host.

This setup *usually* works. Sometimes, though, it seems that Windows (host OS) stops sharing this connection for no reason. What works then is disabling the sharing, saving wi-fi connection options and then adding it again.

This happens *only* when the host OS is returning from sleep (but not always, some sleeps end well).

Can anything be done about it? What's causing the situation?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Check if you have the latest drivers for your wireless adapter, your motherboard, and the latest motherboard BIOS.

Comment: Stop putting the host to sleep with the VMware machine is turned on...

Comment: If you need to do packet tracing, captures, etc., you really should be using bridged mode.

Comment: @allquixotic, I do. :)

Comment: @Ramhound, that's not an option... I use the VM to code and the host is my notebook.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I'll look into that, thanks for the suggestion. (I don't mind having one more hop -- the host, but bridged mode sound interesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the Wireless Adapter in Device Manager and see if there is a Power Management tab?

Wondering if maybe the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" could be causing it?

Comment: Thank you, thank you! That was probably it, because it hasn't happened since I unchecked that option. Thanks!